# Get data from 3 tables and show nice table

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I have 3 tables: users, rooms, room_access.
in users is: user1, user2, user3
in rooms: room1 room2 roomN (i have about 10 rooms)
room_access (room,uid): room1, 1; room2,1; roomN,1; room2,3; room1,3;

So. User3 have access to room1, user2 have access to roome, etc.
In admin area i want to display that: [image: i need that]

Basically table rooms content is displayed table header and table users content is displayed table rows. Maybe there is way that i can select all that data in single query? And where is check symbol, there i want to place checkboxes. So. I don't know how to made that table.

Comment: Please demonstrate what you have tried already - show us a mysql query you have tried, and some (html?) markup you have already got. Please see [ask] a good question.

Comment: i tried nothing. because i am thinking how to get data from database. I would be happy if it was one query. Drawing table in browser not problem. Problem is - how to get data from database ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pivot Table With 3 tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986802/pivot-table-with-3-tables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially you are trying to return the data via a `PIVOT`. MySQL does not have a `PIVOT` function so you can use a combination of aggregate functions and a `CASE` statement. If you know ahead of time the number of rooms that you will have you can use:

```
select u.uname,
  max(case when r.rname = 'room 1' then 'y' else 'n' end) room1,
  max(case when r.rname = 'room 2' then 'y' else 'n' end) room2,
  max(case when r.rname = 'room 3' then 'y' else 'n' end) room3
from users u
left join room_access ra
  on u.uid = ra.userid
left join rooms r
  on ra.roomid = r.rid
group by u.uname
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c2622/3)

But if you have an unknown number of rooms then you can use a [prepared statement to create a dynamic version](http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html)

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(CASE WHEN rname = ''',
      rname,
      ''' THEN ''Y'' ELSE ''N'' END) AS ',
      replace(rname, ' ', '')
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM rooms;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT u.uname, ', @sql, ' 
                  from users u
                  left join room_access ra
                    on u.uid = ra.userid
                  left join rooms r
                    on ra.roomid = r.rid
                  group by u.uname');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c2622/7)